# Gmap view: how to only show certain nodes from a list?

Tags: nodes, views, google-maps

I have a Gmap view that maps markers for all the nodes of a certain content type. Now what I am trying to do is filter the markers by node id. Specifically, I have a list of node id’s that can be different for each user, and I want the map to ONLY show markers for those id’s. Is this possible?

One way to do this would be to use Javascript to remove certain markers from the map after they are already loaded.

Or, perhaps there is a way to create my own custom filter in PHP by hacking the module? If so, where in the module files can I edit the code that creates the array of markers for the map?

(As a further note, i’m fetching the list of node id’s to display on the map from a Parse database object for each user. For example, if Parse returns node id’s 68,70, and 91, how do I map only those nodes?)

Thanks,